# Radio Buttons lose functionality inside a return false element

Tags: jquery, html, forms, radio-button, modal-dialog

So I have a modal with a form. The form has two radio buttons:

[image]

I have this, which stops the modal from closing if the user clicks inside it:

```
$(".modal-content").click(function(e){
    return false;
});
```

However, this prevents radio buttons from being selected (in FF), and in Google / [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/heetertc/Feeuj/1/) you can select once, but not again.

**Does anyone know a way around this?**

I've tried this:

```
$("input:radio").click(function(e){
    return true;
});
```

But it didn't work.

Here's some code [and the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/heetertc/Feeuj/1/):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        // Prevents the modal from closing if the user clicks inside the white box
        $(".modal-content").click(function(e){
            return false;
        });
        $("input:radio").click(function(e){
            console.log("working");
            return true;
        });
    });
</script>

Normal Buttons <br/>
<input type="radio" name="test"><span>Yes</span>
<input type="radio" name="test"><span>No</span><br/><br/>

Return false buttons:<br/>
<div style="border: 1px black solid;" class="modal-content">
    <input type="radio" name="loan"><span>Yes</span>
    <input type="radio" name="loan"><span>No</span>
    <br/><br/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to stop propagation or it will never work.

```
$("input:radio").click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, just found the answer. You have to use stopPropagation(); instead of return false, so:

```
$(".modal-content").click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    //return false;
});
```